# Executing a stored procedure on pervasive server

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures, pervasive

I have a stored procedure on my Pervasive Server called EGC_Expl_BOM_TT and I can execute it with "CALL EGC_Expl_BOM_TT('B-8579-K')" in my SQL query window within Excel, however it will perform the function and then through me an error forcing me to back out of the query window.  I found the below VBA code which is designed to execute a stored procedure.  I need help adapting it to me specific need.  My stored procedure has only one variable input, which I will put in sheet 1 cell A1.

This is my connection string from my Excel query window.  I need help formatting it in the VBA code:

Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties="DSN=global_EGC;ServerName=fah2.1583;UID=UserIDName;PWD=password;ArrayFetchOn=1;ArrayBufferSize=8;TransportHint=TCP;DBQ=GLOBALEGC;ClientVersion=11.31.017.000;CodePageConvert=1252;PvClientEncoding=CP1252;PvServerEncoding=CP1252;AutoDoubleQuote=0;"

```
Function Sproc()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrSproc As String

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=global_EGC;ServerName=fah2.1583;UID=Myusername;PWD=mypassword;ArrayFetchOn=1;ArrayBufferSize=8;TransportHint=TCP;DBQ=GLOBALEGC;ClientVersion=11.31.017.000;CodePageConvert=1252;PvClientEncoding=CP1252;PvServerEncoding=CP1252;AutoDoubleQuote=0;"

'Opens connection to the database
On Error GoTo SQL_ConnectionError
cnn.Open ConnectionString
On Error GoTo 0
'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

Set rst = New ADODB.Connection
StrSproc = "set nocount on; "

StrSproc = "CALL EGC_Expl_BOM_TT" + Cells(1, 1)

rst.ActiveConnection = cnn
On Error GoTo SQL_StatementError
rst.Open StrSproc
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF Then
    Sproc = IIf(IsNull(rst.Fields(0).Value), "(BLANK)", rst.Fields(0).Value)
End If

Exit Function

SQL_ConnectionError:
MsgBox "Error connecting to the server / database. Please check the connection string."
Exit Function

SQL_StatementError:
MsgBox "Error with the SQL syntax. Please check StrSproc."
Debug.Print StrSproc
Exit Function
    SQL_ConnectionError:
    Msgbox "Error connecting to the server / database. Please check the connection string."
    Exit Function

    SQL_StatementError:
    Msgbox "Error with the SQL syntax. Please check StrSproc."
    Debug.Print StrSproc
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: First question, does the stored procedure work correctly through the PCC? Second, you said you're getting an error.  What's the error?

Comment: 1 Yes it does run with "CALL EGC_Expl_BOM_TT('B-8579-K')"

Comment: 2. When I run the CALL in Excel's query window it will execute the procedure but when it completes I get this error:

"The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened. Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or reorganized, then try the operation again."
It the bounces me back into the query windows and I have to back out.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string would be something like:

```
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=global_EGC;ServerName=fah2.1583;UID=UserIDName;PWD=password;ArrayFetchOn=1;ArrayBufferSize=8;TransportHint=TCP;DBQ=GLOBALEGC;ClientVersion=11.31.017.000;CodePageConvert=1252;PvClientEncoding=CP1252;PvServerEncoding=CP1252;AutoDoubleQuote=0;"
```

Your statement would be something like:

```
StrSproc = "EXEC EGC_Expl_BOM_TT" + Cells(1,1)
```

Comment: I modified the code based on your feedback and added it the code to sheet1.  This is the error I get when I run it; with Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection highlighted: "Compile error: User-defined type not defined"